# Hibernate scheme validation fails on JPA+JSONB collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to map a JSONB column to a Set (non built in target), but when the scheme validator runs at the start, it fails as I do not have the join table (which is not required on this model).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_class")
public classs Class extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = ClassSchedule.class) // This is to correctly map the generated meta-model
    @Column(name = "schedules", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "JSONB")
    @Convert(attributeName = "schedules", converter = ClassSchedule.ClassSchedulesConverter.class) //Class's mapper
    private Set<ClassSchedule> schedules;

}
```

Still when I run this code due the fact that I added the `@ElementCollection` annotation, hibernate expects this table `class_schedule` to exists. I know I can disable the scheme-validation from the configuration, but I rather avoid to do so.

Any idea on how to correctly map this field?

Edit:

While I could use `@Type` with hybernate's types (which I originaly did), it would lead to problems on the meta-model generation/mapping:

```
expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.SetAttribute
```

That's why I decide to add `@ElementCollection` which is now prompting the current issue as it's expect a join table.

Comment: `@ElementCollection` implies the elements will be kept in a collection table. Why did you feel you needed this annotation?

Comment: @crizzis As I wrote on the line's comment, it's to correctly generate the meta model (which I use to create queries with the specifications/predicates. So I can't remove it (I rather switch the scheme validation off, but I hope that's not necessary).

Comment: @mark-otteveel could you reconsider marking this question as duplicate?
While I see your point on that both questions are related, this one has some details that make it different.

I know the basic mapping for JSON(B) fields, my particular issue is that I'm trying to deal with the meta-model generation.
If I just follow the basics using Type and Column, then the result is:
'expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.SetAttribute'. That is what lead me to use ElementCollection on the first place.

Comment: This might be a Hibernate metamodel generator bug. `@ElementCollection` is not the solution, though. Of course, the correct metamodel type would be `SingularAttribute` when using a hibernate type or a converter. As a workaround, have you tried using `ClassSchedule[]` instead?

Comment: So I'd just tried it out and replacing the Set with an array works. So I guess it may be a bug on the metamodel generator, will create an issue on it's repo